# Having different server side and database charsets - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm using a cryptographic function in PHP (mcrypt_create_iv). I saw that in my database table that the field which stores this functions return value is of the `latin1_swedish_ci` charset, while in CodeIgniter (config/database.php) the charset is set to `utf8`.

I tested keeping the charset as `utf8` in CI and running the method which stores the encrypted data into the tables column, but it returned a bunch of question marks and stuff that didn't make me feel confident that the mcrypt function worked.

So I changed CIs database charset to `latin1`, which is the same as the field in my databases table. My DB config file now looks like:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

I was wondering if there would be any problem caused by using both `latin1` and `utf8`? I can feel that it just doesn't look right, using two different charsets and all, but in order to use the `mcrypt_create_iv` function (which is used to salt passwords, a big deal imo), I resorted to doing it anyway, hoping it wouldn't affect anything (i.e. inserting/getting data back correctly).

Could someone please shed some light, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: That you see questionsmarks in the database does not mean the data is not correct in the database, because the data is shown as latin, but it is utf8 (for example). However, it is always better to use the same charset in you application, database and connection.

Comment: @Haneev Question marks appear when I have charset as utf8. I wouldn't have resorted to using latin1 if I didn't see so many question marks in the encryption. But are you saying if I keep everything to utf8, the mcrypt function will still be able to decrypt to the correct password?

Answer (score 1):

Using charset `latin` but UTF collation doesn't make a lot of sense. The `latin` charset will turn most unicode characters into "?" since they don't exist in the indicated charset. Using collation based on characters that are not in your chosen charset won't do anything.

So: if you want to be able to store all textual data, you'll want to change your charset utf8, and use utf8_general_ci collation. If you just want `latin1` exclusively (I don't know why you would, but you might...) then use collation rules for latin as well.

If you *do* go with utf8, you'll also want to remember to, when you set up a connect to your database, ensure the connection also uses utf8 for its `charset` and `names`, so that you don't lose text "in transport" between your server and your database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought CI already checked the connection uses utf8 by its config setting which I mentioned? But wouldn't it be pointless to check if the connection also uses utf8 when I know that the fields in my database use latin1_swedish_ci (the default)?

Comment: feel fre to double check on that, but I would prefer to ensure it's utf8 from start to finish rather than to trust CI and discover it doesn't after data started moving